# How to fix error "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'daterange' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime'..."

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a modal that has multiple text areas, a date picker, and a save button. Now if I input some texts on the text areas and save it, it should save and it will show on a datatable.

The problem is I can't save it because of this error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'daterange' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase, System.DateTime, System.String)' in 'TestWeb.Controllers.MainController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

What's weird is my code is working on other computers but not on mine. I even cleared the browser and visual studio's cache, and even uninstall and reinstalled visual studio but still does not work on my pc.

Here is my code for Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string StoreCode, string Purpose, string Dept, string Request, string Type, string detals, string size, int QTY, HttpPostedFileBase Picture, DateTime daterange, string Remarks)
    {

        using (DatawarehouseEntities db = new DatawarehouseEntities())
        {
            string add = db.Add_PRW_Entries(StoreCode, Purpose, Dept, Request, Type, detals, size, QTY, "", Convert.ToDateTime(daterange), Remarks).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

            string filename = Picture.FileName;
            string filepath = "";
            string piclink = "";

            piclink = "//local host link";
            filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + add), filename);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + add)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + add));//create folder if it doesnt exist
            }
            Picture.SaveAs(filepath);

            db.Update_PictureLink_PRW(int.Parse(add), piclink);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }
```

Here is my code for Views:

```
<form action="~/Main/Index" class="needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="insertmain" method="post">
<div class="input-group mb-3">


</div>
<div id="additemmodal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#2c3e50">

                <h2 style="color:white; text-align:center">Add Record</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row has-error">
                <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <div> <label>Request Type:</label></div>
                    <select id="RTYPE" name="RTYPE">
                        @foreach (var items in ViewBag.TYPE)
                        {
                            <option value="@items.Request_Name">@items.Request_Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <div> <label>Business Unit:</label></div>
                    <select id="StoreCode" name="StoreCode">
                        @foreach (var items in ViewBag.cbstore)
                        {
                            <option value="@items.STSHRT">@items.STSHRT - @items.STRNAM</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <div><label><label>Purpose:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Purpose" name="Purpose" required />
                    <div><label><label>Department:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Dept" name="Dept" required />
                    <div><label><label>Request:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Request" name="Request" required />
                    <div><label><label>Type of Materials:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Type" name="Type" required />




                    <div><label><label>Image:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="Picture" name="Picture" onchange="imagePreview()" required />


                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <div><label><label>Details needed in materials:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="detals" name="details" required />
                    <div><label><label>Size:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="size" name="size" required />
                    <div><label><label>Quantity:</label></label></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="QTY" name="QTY" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" required />

                    <div><label><label>Target Date:</label></label></div>
                    <input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" required />
                    <div class="form-group mb-2 imgdiv">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="StoreNumber">Image Preview</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10 imgprv">
                            <img id="imgPreview" src="" data-fancybox />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div><label><label>Remarks:</label></label></div>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="Remarks" name="Remarks" style="margin-left:10px; width:90%;" required></textarea>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-success input-group-text" onclick="confirm()" type="button" id="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="Save" style="display:none"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what to do in order to fix this

Comment: the two different computers have the same system date format?

Comment: Yes it has the same date format

Comment: *"I have a modal that has multiple text areas, a date picker, and a save button"*. That sounds more like a view than a model.